# WinForm: Loading form for InitializeComponent method

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0, biometrics

We have a Windows Form application for our fingerprint scanning for time keeping and it takes **too much time for just initializing the control for the finger print scanning**, around 5 to 10 minutes. So we need to create a loading form so that users will know that the application doesn't hang and they need to wait, but the cause of the long running process was inside the `InitializeComponent()` method from the initialization of the form.

My question is, how can I move the `InitializeComponent()` method to another thread so that I can show a loading form while initializing the form where the biometrics scanner control is, because it creates an error when accessing a UI control from another thread other than the main thread?

My code is in C#, Framework 2.0, build in Visual Studio 2008.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove your control for the finger print scanning from the visual designer and create this control from the code using an additional background thread and writing a progress information during this process.

Answer (score 1):

SO has lot of data about it:

[How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

[Accessing UI in a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709187/accessing-ui-in-a-thread)

[Best Way to Invoke Any Cross-Threaded Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711408/best-way-to-invoke-any-cross-threaded-code)

you can find a lot more.

If still need help, post a comment.

Comment: The links you gave are more for updating the UI in other thread. But my problem is for **initializing** the UI in other thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your `InitializeCompoent();` method in `yourForm.designer.cs`, and from there you can modify it.